# SpringToolSuite 3.7.3 Installer.win32.exe missing in .zip file download

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I downloaded spring-tool-suite-3.7.3.RELEASE-e4.5.2-win32.zip from the official site https://spring.io/tools/sts/all. After unzipping there is no STS installer.exe

According to the STS installation guide I need this to get STS installed.

I am new to STS, please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Erik

Answer (score 3):

The ZIP file of the STS distribution for Windows contains everything you need. There is no installer, you don't need to run an extra install step. Just unpack the ZIP archive (using 7Zip, for example, to avoid issues with too long path names when using the Windows built-in ZIP support), and run the STS.exe (assuming you have a JDK installed already).